Remove trailing whitespaces within [] with sscanf
I need to parse lines returned by utmpdump /var/log/wtmp. They are in this format:
[8] [13420] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:18:29,836564+00:00]
[7] [13611] [ts/3] [john    ] [pts/3       ] [192.168.1.38        ] [192.168.1.38   ] [2024-07-22T11:21:30,065856+00:00]
[8] [13611] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:21:41,814051+00:00]

The characteristics is that:

All columns are wrapped within [],
There is a fixed no of columns per line,
Each column can either contain text or be empty (just spaces). In practice not all of them, but better assume all,
When the column has text, it can vary in length (up to some limit one can prefix, i.e. 64 characters including \0),
When there is text in the column, it will never has preceding spaces, but will often have trailing spaces.

How to parse such a line to 8 char* variables with sscanf specifically? The problem I cannot solve is how to trim trailing spaces and at the same time allow for the in between [] string to vary in length. Is it even possible with sscanf?
I have a working solution without sscanf, but this one has to be done with sscanf specifically. Trimming the whitespaces after sscanf does the parsing is a backup solution, but I am trying to do it with sscanf parse fully.
EDIT: Based on the provided answers, I am looking for a "1 line" sscanf solution. This code fails when there are empty columns, as mentioned in the comments:
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_LEN     (64)

int main (void) 
{
    const char* const line = "[8] [13420] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:18:29,836564+00:00]";
    size_t record_num = 0;
    size_t pid = 0;
    char session_type[BUF_LEN] = { 0 };
    char username[BUF_LEN] = { 0 };
    char terminal[BUF_LEN] = { 0 };
    char source_ip[BUF_LEN] = { 0 };
    char dest_ip[BUF_LEN] = { 0 };
    char timestamp[BUF_LEN] = { 0 };

    sscanf(line, "[%zu] [%zu] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ]", 
        &record_num, &pid, session_type, username, terminal, source_ip, dest_ip, timestamp);
    
    printf("Record number: %zu \n", record_num);
    printf("Pid: %zu \n", pid);
    printf("Session type: %s \n", session_type);
    printf("User name: %s \n", username);
    printf("Terminal: %s \n", terminal);
    printf("Source IP: %s \n", source_ip);
    printf("Destination IP: %s \n", dest_ip);
    printf("Timestamp: %s \n", timestamp);

    return 0;
}

Output:
Record number: 8
Pid: 13420
Session type:
User name:
Terminal:
Source IP:
Destination IP:
Timestamp:

Is there a way to fix the format to account for empty columns without having to parse each column with sscanf individually?

Does it have to be done using sscanf? Why? What is your actual assignment? What are its limitations and requirements?

You should show what you've tried. Answers could then be framed to a level that you might best understand.

I would recommend writing a custom function instead of using sscanf for something that it is not meant to implement simply and fully.

I do have a working solution by manually parsing the string. I was however told that it is possible to do by using sscanf only. I do not have any working sscanf solution, since I do not know how to format the parsing part, as from my end this does not seem to be possible given the provided requirements. I am trying to dervice now whether indeed that is not possible or it is actually.

While it's certainly possible to do using sscanf, it's not trivial. A simple "manual parsing" method might be easier to read, understand and maintain.

My best attempt: https://ideone.com/1Kq6Ae TIL scanf does not like empty strings :-)

I do have a working solution by manually parsing the string Keep it. I need to parse lines Why not use a library that exists for parsing the file utmp.h? utmpdump is written in C, why parse utmpdump output, why not parse the file?  (where "parse" , is really just fread(struct utmp, that's all). Looking at sources, utmpdump has a function undump https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/login-utils/utmpdump.c#L274C13-L274C19 that might be interesting to you. Finally, are you is not a XY question? Do you really care about using specifically sscanf?

Seems like " [%1023[^]]]" does the trick (where the buffer has size 1024).  Just trim the whitespace after the fact.

@KamilCuk the reason is that the code is built with different standard C library than the one that is default on the target. It was easier to just parse the text, as the approach you mentioned I tried in the beginning and I was not able to read any data. Also, regarding XY, I was specifically told its possible to do with just sscanf- I just want to prove it is not (or if it is, learn how).

@WilliamPursell I know that one can trim the spaces after sscanf is called. This is specifically about proving whether its possible by a single sscanf call or not...

The format " [ %N[^]]]" with N the max size of the field  including \0 can read each string and remove heading spaces. But removing ending spaces is not possible in sscanf(), one more step removing them is necessary.

@dalfaB that was exactly what I found out too. Thank you.

If the string doesn't contain spaces then " [%1023[^] ] ]" will remove the trailing whitespace. The %1023[^] ] reads until a space or a ] is met. Then the next  ] will filter any whitespace and match the final ].

@WeatherVane ok, I think the strings are not allowed to have spaces within. Will try this, thank you.

@WeatherVane: the format you propose does not work for fields that contain only spaces.  %1023[^] ] will fail and the rest of the format string  ] will be ignored.  This is the reason why a custom approach is preferrable.

@chqrlie in my test, an input string " [  ] " produces an ouput of "". The scan stops at the first enclosed space, then filters the rest.

@chqrlie I see, there is no conversion performed. If the input is " [  ]  [abc  ]" and the format string contains what I wrote twice, such as sscanf(str, " [%1023[^] ] ] [%1023[^] ] ]", then the second isn't converted either.

@dalfaB "But removing ending spaces is not possible in sscanf()" --> Code does not need to remove them, just scan over them.

Take a step back to think how [s]scanf() processes its format specifier against the string. It (usually) starts by discarding leading whitespace, then does one character at a time matching against the specifier. In your problem, you want it to stop "consuming" and assign for either a (trailing) SP or a ']', then, optionally consume more SP's until a definite ']' is found. As capable as it is, the function is not capable of that. A "one instance of scanf()" will not give you the results you want. Whoever told you it's possible was mistaken (or using an alternative meaning of "one").

Use "%n" to determine offset of scan parts.
Use " " to scan past optional white-spaces.
*scanf() does not like to scan/form 0-length strings, so when scanning a column, consider the [ as part of the string to insure at least 1 character in the string.  Later, start the field one passed the '['.
#include <stdio.h>
#define FN 8

char *cut_up_line(char *offset[FN], char * line) {
  for (int i = 0; i < FN; i++) {
    int field_end;
    int column_end = 0;
    // If possible for the line to include unusually white-spaces,
    // adjust format to include them: "%*[^] \t\r\v\f]%n ] %n"
    sscanf(line, "%*[^] \t]%n ] %n", &field_end, &column_end);
    if (column_end == 0) {
      // debug: printf("-%d <%s>\n", i, line);
      return NULL;
    }
    // Maybe add test here that *line is a '['.
    offset[i] = line + 1;
    line[field_end] = '\0';
    line += column_end;
    // debug: printf("+%d <%s>\n", i, offset[i]);
  }
  return line;
}


void test(char *line) {
  printf("<%s>\n", line);
  char *field[FN];
  if (cut_up_line(field, line) == NULL) {
    printf("** Failed **\n");
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < FN; i++) {
      printf("  %d:<%s>\n", i, field[i]);
    }
  }
}


int main() {
  char s1[] = "[8] [13420] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:18:29,836564+00:00]";
  char s2[] = "[7] [13611] [ts/3] [john    ] [pts/3       ] [192.168.1.38        ] [192.168.1.38   ] [2024-07-22T11:21:30,065856+00:00]";
  char s3[] = "[8] [13611] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:21:41,814051+00:00]";

  test(s1);
  test(s2);
  test(s3);
}

Output
<[8] [13420] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:18:29,836564+00:00]>
  0:<8>
  1:<13420>
  2:<>
  3:<>
  4:<pts/3>
  5:<>
  6:<0.0.0.0>
  7:<2024-07-22T11:18:29,836564+00:00>
<[7] [13611] [ts/3] [john    ] [pts/3       ] [192.168.1.38        ] [192.168.1.38   ] [2024-07-22T11:21:30,065856+00:00]>
  0:<7>
  1:<13611>
  2:<ts/3>
  3:<john>
  4:<pts/3>
  5:<192.168.1.38>
  6:<192.168.1.38>
  7:<2024-07-22T11:21:30,065856+00:00>
<[8] [13611] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:21:41,814051+00:00]>
  0:<8>
  1:<13611>
  2:<>
  3:<>
  4:<pts/3>
  5:<>
  6:<0.0.0.0>
  7:<2024-07-22T11:21:41,814051+00:00>


Some formats deserve being broken up for clarity

#define FMT_ALL_BUT_RBRACKET_WSPACE "%*[^] \t\r\n\f\v]"
...
sscanf(line, FMT_ALL_BUT_RBRACKET_WSPACE "%n ] %n", &field_end, &column_end);


This code takes advantage that line is likely writable and so the tokenized fields are saved in line by adding null characters.  This avoids buffer overflow issues.


UV for the bravery to write this when strtok() and some friends (or one of several other solutions) would do the job without the pseudo-regex complications... Cheers! :-)

Based on your solution, is it possible to do a sscanf ` liner for parsing all of the 8 variables at once?

@ŁukaszPrzeniosło Yes.  Repeat "%*[^] \t]%n ] " 8 times.  That is not elegant though.

@chux-ReinstateMonica this does not parse correctly. Assuming the first 2 items are know to be size_t, did you have this syntax in mind? [%zu] [%zu] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ] [%64[^] ] ]

@ŁukaszPrzeniosło, The format I have in mind in this answer determines the offsets in the string (an int) of the beginning of the field and its end.  To get the beginning offset, minus 1, and the end offset, use "%n%*[^] \t]%n ] " 8 times.  Why do you want to use a single sscanf() call rather than a loop?

@chux-ReinstateMonica I wanted to use 1 call for simplicity. I get your idea now, thanks.

@ŁukaszPrzeniosło " use 1 call for simplicity." --> A loop is more clear, easier to code right and more maintainable. Good luck.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I agree in general, but when going this path, it makes it even more evident its somewhat better to parse it manually.

Here is a simple custom parser for this format:
#include <stdio.h>

// split the line and populate `fields` with pointers to trimmed contents.
int split_log(char *fields[], int n, char *line) {
    char *p = line;
    char *tail;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (*p == ' ')
            p++;
        if (*p != '[')
            break;
        p++;
        fields[i] = p;
        for (tail = p; *p && *p != ']'; p++) {
            if (*p != ' ')
                tail = p + 1;
        }
        if (*p != ']')
            break;
        *tail = '\0';
        p++;
    }
    return i;
}

void print_log(char *fields[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("field%d = '%s'\n", i + 1, fields[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int test_split(char *line, int n) {
    char *fields[8];
    int n1 = split_log(fields, n, line);
    printf("split_log found %d fields:\n", n1);
    print_log(fields, n1);
    return n == n1;
}

int main(void) {
    char line1[] = "[8] [13420] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:18:29,836564+00:00]\n";
    char line2[] = "[7] [13611] [ts/3] [john    ] [pts/3       ] [192.168.1.38        ] [192.168.1.38   ] [2024-07-22T11:21:30,065856+00:00]\n";
    char line3[] = "[8] [13611] [    ] [        ] [pts/3       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2024-07-22T11:21:41,814051+00:00]\n";

    test_split(line1, 8);
    test_split(line2, 8);
    test_split(line3, 8);
    return 0;
}

Output:
split_log found 8 fields:
field1 = '8'
field2 = '13420'
field3 = ''
field4 = ''
field5 = 'pts/3'
field6 = ''
field7 = '0.0.0.0'
field8 = '2024-07-22T11:18:29,836564+00:00'

split_log found 8 fields:
field1 = '7'
field2 = '13611'
field3 = 'ts/3'
field4 = 'john'
field5 = 'pts/3'
field6 = '192.168.1.38'
field7 = '192.168.1.38'
field8 = '2024-07-22T11:21:30,065856+00:00'

split_log found 8 fields:
field1 = '8'
field2 = '13611'
field3 = ''
field4 = ''
field5 = 'pts/3'
field6 = ''
field7 = '0.0.0.0'
field8 = '2024-07-22T11:21:41,814051+00:00'


How to parse such a line to 8 char * variables with sscanf specifically?

Assuming all fields contain at least one character, possibly white space, the above function can be implemented using sscanf for most of the work, but I'm afraid the code is less readable and more difficult to apprehend:
// split the line and populate `fields` with pointers to trimmed contents.
int split_log(char *fields[], int n, char *line) {
    char *p = line;
    char open[2], close[2];
    int i, begin, end;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (sscanf(p, " %1[[]%n%*[^]]%n%1[]]", open, &begin, &end, close) != 2)
            break;
        fields[i] = p + begin;
        while (p[end - 1] == ' ')
            end--;
        p[end] = '\0';
        p += end + 1;
    }
    return i;
}


The problem I cannot solve is how to trim trailing spaces and at the same time allow for the in between [] string to vary in length. Is it even possible with sscanf?

As you can see in the above code, the trimming is still performed with custom code.  There is no simple way to trim the trailing spaces with sscanf, yet it is possible to use sscanf in a convoluted way to avoid manually testing the buffer contents, and thus further obfuscate the code:
        // while (p[end - 1] == ' ')
        //    end--;
        while (sscanf(p + end - 1, "%1[ ]", open))
            end--;

However, if the field contents contains at most one word, you could use sscanf to compute the length of this word:
int split_log(char *fields[], int n, char *line) {
    char *p = line;
    char open[2], close[2];
    int i, begin, end, len;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (sscanf(p, " %1[[]%n%*[^]]%n%1[]]", open, &begin, &end, close) != 2)
            break;
        fields[i] = p + begin;
        p[end] = '\0';
        len = 0;
        sscanf(p + begin, "%*s%n", &len);
        p[begin + len] = '\0';
        p += end + 1;
    }
    return i;
}

sscanf is a powerful tool, but full of quirks and pitfalls. It is easy to misuse even for simple parsing tasks. For such cases, writing custom code is a safer way to get correct results.
